# *[class].tdwrap css in email

Tags: css, class, html-email

I am looking into doing some emails with html and css and been looking at the source code of some emails and i came across this decloration of the css in the head of a few emails.

```
*[class].tdwrap{display: inline-block !important;}
*[class].vspacer{ margin-left: 50px; }
```

I know that * usually means "all" but i have never seen the [class] part before and cant find a articles about it by doing several google searches.

Any ideas on what that means?

This was taken from the the source of an AppleMail email, maybe it is and AppleMail thing only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[class]` is an attribute selector and when it's preceeded by the universal selector (`*`) it selects any element that has a class attribute set on it, irregardless of what the attribute value may be.

Learn a bit more about selectors from the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and direction to the documentation.

Comment: what's the practical purpose of such a selector though? doesn't the `.tdwrap` qualifier *imply* the element having a class anyway?

Comment: @PerfectDark: sorry if I'm being thick... `*[class].tdwrap` matches: `*` any element `[class]` that has a *class* attribute `.tdwrap` that has a *tdwrap* class. If I have an element `<div class="tdwrap">...</div>`, it will match that selector. If I add a class *tdwrap*, **I can't do so without adding a class attribute**. Right? *Edit:* what I'm saying is `*[class].tdwrap` will match same elements as `*.tdwrap` or even just `.tdwrap` for that matter. So why bother?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors).  It selects any element that has this attribute (regardless of its value).

Answer (score 1):

The `[class]` selector matches any element with the `class` attribute set (to any value). It's a standard CSS attribute selector, as defined in [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector). I don't think it does anything here, since the `.tdwrap` and `.vspacer` require class attributes already.

The selectors could be replaced with just their class selectors.

Comment: Thank you for the direction and answer